# I tried to deploy gRPC (go) server in docker and expose port in local port but port bindings are not working

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, grpc, grpc-go

I tried to deploy gRPC server and mongodb in docker. After that I trying to binding docker ports to my local ports. mongodb ports binding was working fine. But, gRPC server ports are not binding my local port

```
ports:
  - "50051:50051"
```

like this i tried in docker-compose.yml

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  auth_server:
    container_name: auth_service
    build: .
    command: go run server.go
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/auth_server
    working_dir: /go/src/auth_server
    ports:
      - "50051:50051"
    environment:
      PORT: 50051
```

In client gRPC file I used host and port like, **0.0.0.0:50051**

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("0.0.0.0:50051", grpc.WithInsecure())
```

but it was not working. I can't find any bug, so I assume I am doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `127.0.0.1:50051` when connecting from a client on the host machine, or `auth_server:50051` if you are connecting from docker-compose network.

Comment: but `docker ps -a` it is showing ports like `0.0.0.0:50051->50051/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on windows I would check the "reserved port ranges" with command

```
 netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

Also see [this thread on github](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171).

If it's linux check that nothing on the host is binding on that port.